# Redirect to location on Google Map, when click the area using React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have developed a web application with React.js. There are some places to display in my application. So I want to allow users to click on those places(areas) and redirect them to the location on Google Maps. I tried a lot of plugins for that. But no successful results were obtained. Is there a good plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a list of places in your application and you want to show it's position in the Google Map every time that place is clicked, am I correct? You can put an `onClick` eventlistener to the html element of those places and pass the coordinate of that place and plot it to the map. You can also implement this without using any react libraries for Google Maps.

Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/geocoding-app-clickplace-shvk5k?file=package.json) where I implement it. Each time the place will be clicked, it will trigger the `handleClick event` and pass the address name to Geocoding API where it will geocode the address(convert it to coordinates). This coordinate will then be use to plot a marker in the map.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

var map;
const API_KEY = "PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";
class GeocodingApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src =
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` +
        API_KEY +
        `&libraries=geometry,places`;
      script.id = "googleMaps";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        this.renderMap();
      });
    } else {
      this.renderMap();
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    const coords = { lat: 41.375885, lng: 2.177813 };
    const el = document.getElementById("map");

    if (el) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
          lat: coords.lat,
          lng: coords.lng,
        },
      });

      return map;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleClick(data) {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.codeAddress(geocoder, data.place);
    document.getElementById("chosen").innerHTML = "You clicked: " + data.place;
  }

  codeAddress(geocoder, add) {
    let address = add;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {
      if (status === "OK") {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
        });
        return marker;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h1>ADD YOUR API KEY TO MAKE IT WORKING</h1>

        <div id="map" />
        <div id="panel">
          <h3 id="chosen">Please choose a Place:</h3>
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { place: "Sydney" })}
            value="Sydney"
          />
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { place: "Boston" })}
            value="Boston"
          />
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { place: "New York" })}
            value="New York"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<GeocodingApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```